# Execution of Sequence a chain of async web requests with Retrofit and LiveData in android

Tags: android, retrofit, android-livedata

So I have three `retrofit web requests` that call from **MainActivity** and each call won't depend on each other.

So let's say first one is `getImages()` , second `getCountry()`, and the final one `getUser()`

But  have a condition that the next activity shouldn't load until all these request are executed successfully.

So I have two options here

1) Create **nested request** and execute each request onSuccess On each
    response . This seems reliable but hence these are async call I need
    to optimize the time.
 2) Create a variable and increment it on
    each success call , this approach seems time saving but I'm not sure
    this is good practice.

So is there any way that I can get this done . .and I'm not using **RxAndroid**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MediatorLiveData`. For each request declare a `LiveData` `boolean` flag and every time request finish check all three flag in `MediatorLiveData`, if they all `true` set `MediatorLiveData` `true` then observe it and go next activity

You can get details and code samples from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. All itemList objects implement with ObservableDataset
2. MainActivity implement Observer.
3. **in OnChange method**; 
   When cities/images/users loaded, isLoadedCities/isLoadedImages/isLoadedUsers set true and then triggered inValidate().
4. **inInvalidate method**;
   Check all IsLoaded flags has been true then triggered doSomething()